# DIScomfort yet UNcomfortable

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, prefixes, derivational-morphology, negative-prefixes

Why is the negation of *comfort* *discomfort* but the opposite of *comfortable* is *uncomfortable*? Or is the word "discomfortable" accepted too?

Comment: See also unable (adjective) and disable (verb).

Comment: I've never heard of "discomfortable," but apparently, the word [uncomfort](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=uncomfort) is [coming back](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uncomfort&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuncomfort%3B%2Cc0) into use.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the negating prefix "un-" is very productive on adjectives, and less common on other parts of speech.

Compare also "misfortune" and "unfortunate", or "disbelief" and "unbelievable".

That's not to say that "un-" never appears on nouns. For example, "[unbelief](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disbelief%2C%20unbelief&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisbelief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbelief%3B%2Cc0)" is used, although not as often as "disbelief".

Adjectives can also have negative prefixes other than "un-", although it's not very common. The adjective "misfortunate" technically also exists, although the OED says it is "Chiefly Sc[ottish]." A small number of people seem to use "[disbelievable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disbelievable%2C%20unbelievable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisbelievable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbelievable%3B%2Cc0)", but it's so rare or so recent that it doesn't have an OED entry. "[Discomfortable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discomfortable%2C%20uncomfortable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscomfortable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuncomfortable%3B%2Cc0)" also has negligible use, and is only notable because it was apparently used in the Shakespeare play *King Richard II.* I wouldn't recommend the use of any of these adjectives.

But, an example of an adjective starting with "dis-" that exists in standard English is "disagreeable".